# PHP 7.3 SoapClient stream_context (verify_peer) Ignored

Tags: php, ssl, soap, soap-client, php-7.3

I'm in the process of upgrading from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.3 and it appears that a SoapClient in PHP 7.3 ignores the ssl `verify_peer` option.

In PHP 5.6 the following code executes as it should:

```
$opts = [
    'ssl' => [
        'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT,
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ],
];
$stream_context = stream_context_create($opts);
$options = [
    'stream_context' => $stream_context,
];
$client = new SoapClient("https://...?wsdl", $options);
$client->SomeMethod();
```

In PHP 7.3 executing the same code results in `PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://...?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://...?wsdl"`

I've tried including `verify_peer_name => false` in `$opts`; `allow_self_signed => true` (although the cert isn't self-signed - just not signed by any trusted certs on the machine the code is running on).  I've also tried including the `cafile` (in .pem format) for the Root CA that signed the remote certificate, as well as the whole cert chain (in .pem format).  Additionally I've tried to include the `capath` option, pointing to a directory where I've saved the Root CA, as well as the cert chain.

If I try to bypass downloading the wsdl via providing a `uri` and `location`, I receive the error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in...`

I haven't found anything in the differences between 5.6 and 7.3 so far that would explain the difference in behavior I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

After too much time spent on this it looks like PHP 7 does actually respect the `stream_context` `verify_peer` option.  The root of the problem was that the "default" ciphers used when negotiating a connection changed between PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.3.  Explicitly calling out the cipher(s) to be used allowed the SoapClient to communicate in PHP 7.3.7.

```
$opts = [
    'ssl' => [
        'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'ciphers' => 'RC4-SHA',
    ],
];
$stream_context = stream_context_create($opts);
$options = [
    'stream_context' => $stream_context,
];
$client = new SoapClient("https://...?wsdl", $options);
$client->SomeMethod();
```